# How to show Device date and time in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, date

Always i'm struggling with NSDate in iphone apps. I have developed one iphone app for US based client. The app should show the todays date. I have used the following code in my app. The date is showing correctly for me(Am in India). But, the date is also showing the india date for my client in (US). I want to show the date from the iphone/ipad device.

```
    NSDate *today1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSString *dates = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[today1 description]];
dates = [dates substringToIndex:10];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dates];
```

How to do this? Any suggestions/sample code to solve this? I has spend 6 hours to solve my problem but, i didn't find the answer? Please help me. Thanks to spend your valuable time with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Locale
See code blow Taken from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-SW53)

```
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSLocale *gbLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];

NSString *dateFormat;
NSString *dateComponents = @"yMMMMd";

dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:dateComponents options:0 locale:usLocale];
```

---

**Updated answer below**

I have tested this should work out of the box any where is the world.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];  
[dateFormat release];
NSLog(@"Date: %@:", dateString);
```

Comment: I have used above line in my code but it showing one warning like 'Incomplete Objective-C types assigning 'Struct NSString *', expected 'struct NSDateFormatter'. This is i tried,

Comment: NSString *dateComponents = @"MMM d yyyy";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

//[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"] autorelease]];// I tried this line also, i dont know it working fine because now 24.10.2011 in US also..

dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:dateComponents options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]; // App getting crash after crashing after across this line

[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];  
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d yyyy"];

Comment: Thanks for your advise, i will remove the line @"en_GB" from my code. I applied your last altered code but, it is also showing the same warning and app getting crash. I have hope you can solve my problem. Am also trying my level best. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi friend. I have tried these lines,

NSLocale *currentLoc = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[dateFormatter setLocale:currentLoc]; 

Is it correct?

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot. Now am using your updated answer. I have found this from your link (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that was provided by you in morning. Once again i thank you. I hope your updated answer will work perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
    [dateFormat setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. I have one more doubt, can it will work in other country users? Can you please clarify my doubt?